# How can I organize a glut of mysql tables?

Tags: mysql

Our development database now has 263 tables.  During development we only work with a few.  Is there anyway to organize all the tables into something like folders?

Comment: Can you expand on this a a bit. Are you saying that only a few of the tables are current or that all the tables are current but used for different things.

Comment: Is for development, why bother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to organize tables hierarchically that is meaningful to MySQL.

As others have noted, you can maintain separate schemas (in MySQL, databases), or you can develop and use a table naming structure that organizes your tables in a way that is meaningful to users (but is still not meaningful to MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that occurs to me is to use different databases for different sets of tables. See CREATE DATABASE

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to organize tables other than to move them into other dbs.  What you could do is prefix the ones you use frequently so they are always at the top (this only works though if you have defined constants for your table names for just such an occasion so you don't have to trudge through your source code changing every instance it is called).