# Is it possible to organize tables or others object in folder?

Tags: mysql

i would like to organize my tables, querys etc in a visualizations like folder. 
I need this to have a better visualizations of my software. 
Is it possible in MySql ? 
With others DBMS ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I organize a glut of mysql tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217157/how-can-i-organize-a-glut-of-mysql-tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my question is duplicate of [How can I organize a glut of mysql tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217157/how-can-i-organize-a-glut-of-mysql-tables)

And i can argue, there's no possibility to organize them hierarchically ... :(!

Answer (score 2):

With tools like mysql workbench you can draw your schema
http://dev.mysql.com/workbench/