# How to organize MySQL tables names

Tags: mysql

It's possible to create a group for organize MySQL tables?

Like PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM articles;
SELECT * FROM articles.comments;
SELECT * FROM articles.author;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217157/how-can-i-organize-a-glut-of-mysql-tables) points out, there is no way to organize MySQL tables other than to move them to a separate database or to create your own naming convention.  With regard to the naming convention you chose in your question, this also will not work.  From the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html):

> Database and table names cannot contain “/”, “\”, “.”, or characters that are not permitted in file names.

You can try using underscores if this would help.